# Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration

Tags: node.js, typescript

hi everyone im new to typescript and node and trying to make a chat app using stream.io and typescript. Now im trying to get all messagess from a specific channell in getallmessages function. however when i call this function to test it im getting error     saying Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration. Can someone please tell me how i can call this function so i can display response to console ? thanks !

```
import { StreamChat } from 'stream-chat';

import { appConfig } from '@/config';

export class ChatService {
  public static masterHealthBotUserId = 'masterHealthBot';

  private static client = StreamChat.getInstance(
    appConfig.get('getstream').apiKey,
    appConfig.get('getstream').apiSecret,
  );

  /**
   * Creates get stream chat token that can be used by the client to connect to getStream
   * @param userId - User Id
   * @param expiry - expiration time of token. If undefined then token wont expire
   */
  public createToken({ userId, expiry }: { userId: number; expiry?: number }) {
    return ChatService.client.createToken(userId.toString(), expiry);
  }

// function that im trying to call but its giving me error 
public async getallmessages(podId: string) {

const channel = ChatService.client.channel('messaging', podId);
const messageFilter = { id: { $exists: true } };
const response = await channel.search(messageFilter);
console.log(response.results);
  }}

}


   getallmessages('3');
```

}

Comment: You can't call method of the `ChatService` class outside of it. you can call it by `(new ChatService).getallmessages('3')`

Comment: so how do i make a new intance of this class with typescript?

Comment: it's like javascript => `let chatService = new ChatService()`